# Cannot find module 'msw/node' from

Tags: node.js, jestjs, next.js13, msw

I am using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to mock server requests. I recently updated to [v2](https://mswjs.io/blog/introducing-msw-2.0/), after which began seeing a `module not found` error when trying to import `setupServer` from the `msw/node` import path. I can see the file in my node modules folder, I know it is there. What would cause this issue? How can I fix it?

Node version: 20.9.0 (current lts)

Pnpm version: 8.10.0

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.15",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.15",
    "awilix": "^9.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "joi": "^17.11.0",
    "joi-password": "^4.1.1",
    "jotai": "^2.5.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^14.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.47.0",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.39.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/cookies": "^0.7.9",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.7",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.200",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.33",
    "@types/zxcvbn": "^4.4.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.6.0",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "msw": "^2.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.19"
  }
}
```

ts config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "./jest.setup.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

jest config

```
import nextJest from 'next/jest';
import { Config } from 'jest';

module.exports = nextJest({ dir: '.' })({
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
} as Config);
```

jest setup file

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

file where error occurs

```
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);

export default server;
```

error

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'msw/node' from 'path/to/file.ts'
```

Comment: https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1786, https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x#cannot-find-module-mswnode-jsdom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is probably related with `msw` migration from v1 to v2. In the documentation you can find your issue described [here](https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x#cannot-find-module-mswnode-jsdom)

From the docs:

> This error is thrown by your test runner because JSDOM uses the browser export condition by default. This means that when you import any third-party packages, like MSW, JSDOM forces its browser export to be used as the entrypoint. This is incorrect and dangerous because JSDOM still runs in Node.js and cannot guarantee full browser compatibility by design.

> To fix this, set the `testEnvironmentOptions.customExportConditions` option in your `jest.config.js` to `['']`:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: [''],
  },
}
```

This will force JSDOM to use the default export condition when importing `msw/node`, resulting in correct imports.

Comment: This did solve that specific problem, after working through the documented "common issues" though there are still issues preventing my tests from running. I ended up downgrading. I will try again and see if the newer library version works in the future.